# Check if a numpy array is sorted

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and I like to check if it is sorted.

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Also see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8392

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
np.all(a[:-1] <= a[1:])
```

Examples:

```
is_sorted = lambda a: np.all(a[:-1] <= a[1:])

>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,9])
>>> is_sorted(a)
True

>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,3])
>>> is_sorted(a)
False
```

Comment: Solution also mentioned here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8392

Comment: This solution is about twice as fast as `np.all(np.diff(a) >= 0)`, the top answer as of writing this.

Comment: This is the correct solution, because np.diff uses the implementation of __sub__, which does not have to have anything to do with sorting, in case of general arbitrary types. In particular using the difference fails on unsigned numerical types. This uses <= which defines sorting.

Comment: While this answer is perfectly correct for a numpy array, I caution others against using this answer for non-numpy ndarrays.  For example,`is_sorted((0, 10, 1))` gives `True`.  That is be careful not to apply this to any array that is `array_like`, it has to be an ndarray.  It might be safer to use `np.asanyarray` first if you are unsure.

Answer (score 44):

With NumPy tools:

```
np.all(np.diff(a) >= 0)
```

but numpy solutions are all O(n).

If you want quick code and very quick conclusion on unsorted arrays:

```
import numba
@numba.jit
def is_sorted(a):
    for i in range(a.size-1):
         if a[i+1] < a[i] :
               return False
    return True
```

which is  O(1) (in mean) on random arrays.

Comment: Re "numpy solutions are all O(n)" -- I suppose the answer below (`np.all(a[:-1] <= a[1:])`) is not O(n). Is it?

Comment: it is. np.all is not lazy.

Comment: @B.M. I wonder if you can call this O(1). O notation is the "worst case", right? Then in the worst case scenario, you will be traversing every element in array, which is O(n). Do you agree?

Comment: I think your edit doesn't help as Θ(1) is even stronger than O(1). You could do an average-case analysis, but for most practical purposes, it may be sufficient to replace your O() bound by the less formal sentence "it early exits".

Comment: This is definitely not Θ(1). The worst case is that you traverse all elements, and the average case is that you traverse half of the elements (assuming a uniform distribution of elements and thus a uniform distribution of the index of the first pair of consecutive elements where the first element is not >= the second). Therefore, this is Θ(n) for *both* the worst case *and* the average case—which of course also implies O(n).

Comment: @Anakhand that is not correct, a random array has an expected time to first inversion of ½ + 2/4 + ⅜  + 4/16 + 5/32 + ..., which equals 2.

Comment: WARNING: This does not work if the array dtype is unsigned. Or if __sub__ has been overloaded to something else, probably.

Answer (score 6):

The inefficient but easy-to-type solution:

```
(a == np.sort(a)).all()
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, the O(log n) iterative solution is found below. The recursive version is slower and crashes with big vector sizes. However, it is still slower than the native numpy using `np.all(a[:-1] <= a[1:])` most likely due to modern CPU optimizations. The only case where the O(log n) is faster is on the "average" random case or if it is "almost" sorted. If you suspect your array is already fully sorted then np.all will be faster.

```
def is_sorted(a):
    idx = [(0, a.size - 1)]
    while idx:
        i, j = idx.pop(0) # Breadth-First will find almost-sorted in O(log N)
        if i >= j:
            continue
        elif a[i] > a[j]:
            return False
        elif i + 1 == j:
            continue
        else:
            mid = (i + j) >> 1 # Division by 2 with floor
            idx.append((i, mid))
            idx.append((mid, j))
    return True

is_sorted2 = lambda a: np.all(a[:-1] <= a[1:])
```

Here are the results:

```
# Already sorted array - np.all is super fast
sorted_array = np.sort(np.random.rand(1000000))

%timeit is_sorted(sorted_array)
659 ms ± 3.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit is_sorted2(sorted_array)
431 µs ± 35.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
# Here I included the random in each command so we need to substract it's timing
%timeit np.random.rand(1000000)
6.08 ms ± 17.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit is_sorted(np.random.rand(1000000))
6.11 ms ± 58.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# Without random part, it took 6.11 ms - 6.08 ms = 30µs per loop

%timeit is_sorted2(np.random.rand(1000000))
6.83 ms ± 75.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# Without random part, it took 6.83 ms - 6.08 ms = 750µs per loop
```

Net, a O(n) vector optimized code is better than an O(log n) algorithm, unless you will run >100 million element arrays.

Comment: I think that the recursive version of this algorithm could be parallelized, with the `(i, mid)` and `(mid, j)` tasks running simultaneously.

Comment: @Jasha you would soon hit the limits of the CPU, because only a finite number of threads can be run simultaneously. Besides, since this is Python, the GIL makes multithreading a major pain

Comment: Hmm... If your CPU supports e.g. 16 threads, you could implement the parallelism to kick in at recursion depth 4 (i.e. after the array has been split in half 4 times, so that there are 16 subarrays). Splitting the problem at this point, so that there are 16 threads, should give a speedup for very large, nearly-sorted arrays. As you mentioned @vikarjramun, maybe Python is not the best-suited programming language...

Comment: @Jasha Most likely it will be slower with the multi-threading proposal also, given the overhead to map-reduce the result set. I think many people misunderstand vectorization (CPU SSE/AVX assembler instruction set) and how efficient it is compared to anyting else. The point of my post was to exactly show this. For example even the pure C compiler is not able to optimize the code that well and does *NOT* generate SSE/AVX instruction, whereas using pyton, the SSE/AVX assembler instructions are embedded in the numpy source code.