# python Numppy array get the last 3 values to identify its accending or decending or inorder

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, sorting

I am trying to do the following with NumPy array or normal array:

For push the data I am doing:

```
ar1 = []

#Read from Pandas dataframe column. i is row number of data - it's working fine.
ar1.append((df['rolenumber'][i]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[34768, 34739, 34726, 34719, 34715]
```

This result possible to come as Ascending/Descending or combined anything possible.

Here I want to take the last 3 values to validate whether it is ascending or descending or mixed.

- **Ascending**: If the last 3 values increased regular. Example: `34726, 34739, 34745`
- **Descending**: If the last 3 values decrease properly. Example: `34726, 34719, 34715`
- **Mixed**: If the last 3 start with a big number then small number then big number. Example: `34726, 34719, 34725`

Note: No need to sort only validate.

Comment: Even if the last 3 values are  sorted doesn't mean the entire array is sorted ?

Comment: possible . can array have more then 3 values.  that will be update each time- while each time push i have to validate  only the last 3 . if the condtion match or not . no worry about the previous values

Comment: only the last 3 values have to validate .   that ascending order or descending order  or  No  order

Comment: You don't really need advanced knowledge of numpy if you just need to check if 3 values are sorted ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a numpy array is sorted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47004506/check-if-a-numpy-array-is-sorted)

Answer (score 1):

This little snippet should get you going:

```
a = np.array([34768, 34739, 34726, 34719, 34715])

is_descending = np.all(np.diff(a[-3:]) < 0)
is_ascending = np.all(np.diff(a[-3:]) > 0)
is_mixed = ~(is_ascending | is_descending)
```